# Delete Permission on ON CRUD access at object level for users

Tags: profile, permission-sets, custom-profile, custom-permission

I have a requirement i have custom object(Broker__c) and i have Profile(Sales) we have around 100 users in the profile . We need to remove delete permission for 10 users. The object has all the CRUD access at profile level . We doon't want to create another profile as well.
The permission set is used to provide additional access to users . How could we achieve  this scenario?

[image]

Thanks,
Vijay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario you may have to give the minimum access using the profile and add extra access using permission set .

i'e you may have to remove the delete access for the object at profile level and create a permission set with delete access and assign this permission set for other 90 users as we cannot restrict the access using permission sets.

You may also use the concept of muting permission set in this scenario . please find the below [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.perm_set_groups_create_mute.htm&type=5) for the same. But it is always better to have the least permissions at profile level and add extra using permission sets.

Comment: Is there any other way we can use it apart from assigning the permission set to 90 users another way we can use custom permissions .

Comment: I don't hope the custom permission can help in this scenario. Even custom permissions need to be assigned to profile or permission set I guess.

Comment: We have an other option calling muting permission set . I have added the same to the answer as well.